# Visual WebPart for Adding Picture and Updating metadata

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-web-part

- I want to create a visual web part to add images by using upload ASP
  UI controls
- And while uploading it should also save relevant metadata like Title
  and Description

Don't have much experience in creating Visual web-part. So please requesting for relevant links and code snippets.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

namespace TSInfo_Intranet.File_Upload
{
public partial class File_UploadUserControl : UserControl
{
    string siteURL = "";
    string listTitle = "Company Document";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }

    protected void BtnSave_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uploadDocument();

    }

    public void uploadDocument()
    {
        if (fuUploadFile.PostedFile != null && fuUploadFile.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                SPSite siteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPList spList = web.Lists.TryGetList(listTitle);
                {
                    {
                        byte[] contents;
                        using (Stream filestream = fuUploadFile.PostedFile.InputStream)
                        {
                            contents = new byte[filestream.Length];
                            filestream.Read(contents, 0, 
                            (int)filestream.Length);
                            filestream.Close();
                            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fuUploadFile.PostedFile.FileName);
                            string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fuUploadFile.PostedFile.FileName);
                            spList.RootFolder.Files.Add(spList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + fileName, contents, true);
                            spList.Update();
                            SetupMetadata(web,spList,fileName,fileNameWithoutExtension);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                lblMessage.Text = ex.StackTrace;
                lblCheckMesaage.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Select a File";
        }
    }
    public void SetupMetadata(SPWeb spWeb, SPList spList, string title, string fileNameWithoutExtension)
    {
        try
        {
            string fullFilePath = siteURL + spList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + title;
            SPFile newFile = spWeb.GetFile(fullFilePath);
            SPListItem item = spList.Items[newFile.UniqueId];
            item["Title"] = fileNameWithoutExtension;
            item["Language"] = spList.Fields["Language"].GetFieldValue(ddlLanguage.SelectedValue);
            item["Department"] = spList.Fields["Department"].GetFieldValue(ddlDepartment.SelectedValue);
            item.Update();
            spWeb.Update();
          }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Error ocuured";             
        }  
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try the code demo in the post ?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the code demo below to upload file and set metadata column value in Visual Web Part:

ascx:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
    Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="VisualWebPartProject3.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl" %>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Language:</td>
    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddllang" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Select Language</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>English</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Hindi</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Kannad</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Document Type:</td>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddldoctype" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Select Document Type</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>IT</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>HR</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>FINANCE</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Select File:</td>
        <td><asp:FileUpload ID="fuUploadFile" runat="server" />  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="105px" OnClick="BtnSave_Click1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblCheckMesaage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ascx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy;
using System.IO;

namespace VisualWebPartProject3.VisualWebPart1
{
    public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
    {
        string siteURL = "http://sp/sites/dev/";
        string listTitle = "Documents";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

            }

        }
        public void SetupMetadata(SPWeb spWeb, SPList spList, string title, string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                string fullFilePath = siteURL + spList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + fileName;
                SPFile newFile = spWeb.GetFile(fullFilePath);
                newFile.CheckIn("checked in");
                SPListItem item = spList.Items.GetItemById(newFile.Item.ID);
                item.File.CheckOut();
                item["Title"] = fileName;
                item["Language"] = spList.Fields["Language"].GetFieldValue(ddllang.SelectedValue);
                item["Department"] = spList.Fields["Department"].GetFieldValue(ddldoctype.SelectedValue);
                item.Update();
                item.File.CheckIn("checked in");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Error ocuured";
            }
        }


        public void uploadDocument()
        {
            if (fuUploadFile.PostedFile != null && fuUploadFile.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    SPSite siteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
                    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                    SPList spList = web.Lists.TryGetList(listTitle);
                    {
                        {
                            byte[] contents;
                            using (Stream filestream = fuUploadFile.PostedFile.InputStream)
                            {
                                contents = new byte[filestream.Length];
                                filestream.Read(contents, 0, (int)filestream.Length);
                                filestream.Close();

                                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fuUploadFile.PostedFile.FileName);
                                string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fuUploadFile.PostedFile.FileName);
                                spList.RootFolder.Files.Add(spList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + fileName, contents, true);
                                spList.Update();
                                SetupMetadata(web, spList, listTitle, fileName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    lblMessage.Text = ex.StackTrace;
                    lblCheckMesaage.Text = ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Select a File";
            }
        }

        protected void BtnSave_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uploadDocument();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Jerry, Since i am in process of doing environment setup i have just reformatted the code which i am going to try. Could you kindly have a look if its OK ?

Comment: Never mind, I will test your code in my side tomorrow and will update to your if there is any progress.

Comment: I will update the code snippet I tested and result capture in the reply for your reference.

Comment: You can check the code snippet in my post now.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I will try and let me know

Comment: Hi Sukumar, Do you have any updates ?

Comment: Hi Jerry, Sorry. I work at mutiple places so forgot to update.
Yes. I am having a problem with this line.

spList.RootFolder.Files.Add(siteURL + listTitle + "/" + fileName, contents, true);

It says object reference set to null value. :(

Any idea ?

Comment: Please check my code snippet above carefully, this line has been changed to  spList.RootFolder.Files.Add(spList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + fileName, contents, true);

Comment: spList.RootFolder.Files.Add(spList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + fileName, contents, true);

Tried jerry, am getting same error